# Caching the elements inside the trace of a matrix

Tags: matlab, trace

I have this evaluation to make like

D = trace(ABC)

A and C are constant matrices which do not change. B matrix keeps on changing. What I want is to find a way to store some values from A and C, so that I don't have to calculate the product ABC all the time. B will change and I will just use some kind of product of the elements of B with some cached version of AC or something like that.

I know trace(ABC) = trace(BCA) so I can precalculate the product CA but CA is very high dimensional so it won't fit in memory. Hence I cannot do it. ABC turns out to be low dimensional so it is fine

```
C is of size 40000x10 and dense
B  of size 80000x40000 but B is sparse so it is fine
A is of size 10 by 80000 and dense
```

Any suggestions how I can do it efficiently?

Comment: I've racked my brains on this for a few minutes: never come across this before. If the matrices were square then you may have been able to use eigenvalues and diagonalisation. Perhaps you could ask on the mathematics site.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about tr(ABC) element-wise,

[image]

l=10, n=40000, m=80000.

The number of multiplications of the above using the sparsity of `B` is np*10, where np is the number of nonzero elements of B.

The number of multiplication of pre-computing CA is 10*40000*80000. After that, using the sparsity of B, the number of multiplication of tr(B(CA)) is np. Thus, unless you do the this computation more than 1/(density of B) times, just calculating tr(ABC) is faster.

That being said, I don't think pre-computation of CA is necessary.